# Setting focus on page load in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I can't seem to get focus to set on page load. Here is what I'm trying to do right now:

INPUT:

```
<ion-input placeholder="SCAN LP TO ACKNOWLEDGE" type="number" [(ngModel)]="this.session.listService.licensePlate" required (keyup.enter)="ValidateAndAcknowledge()" #myInput ></ion-input>
```

TS FILE

```
export class AcknowledgePage {
  @ViewChild('input') myInput;

  constructor() {
      }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.myInput);
      this.myInput.setFocus();

    }, 150);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your ViewChild refers 'input' while your template states #myInput. You need to fix that:

```
export class AcknowledgePage {
  @ViewChild('myInput') myInput;

  constructor() {
      }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.myInput);
      this.myInput.setFocus();

    }, 150);

  }
}
```

Now even if this code will work for you on Android devices - this may not work on latest iOS (11.3+) since Apple actually wants users to trigger focus via explicit tap action and not programmatic-ally.

Comment: Is there a better approach? This will be an ionic Cordova android app

Comment: not really, I was checking this recently and didn;t find a better and more elegant solution. But can you describe better your use case maybe? you want on a page load to ensure there is a focus and hence virtual keyboard is there instantly or? what are you tryin gto solve?

Comment: That is correct. There is an input field on page where they will use a barcode scanner to scan a barcode. This will trigger and auto enter after the scan. But I want the focus to be set there when the page loads so there is really no interaction with the page itself.

Comment: got it and current code - what is "bad" about it? it works but there are issues or? Can you elaborate what would you want to work differently? Also your code currently points to ionViewDidLoad lifecycle which only fires once when the code of your component (page) gets loaded into memory. You probably need to use ionViewDidEnter hook here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but @viewChild is not working for me at the end I used document.querySelector() in ionViewDidLoad() and set focus() and It's work for me.[image]